# How to get dynamic RadioButton tooltip in Java?

Tags: java, swing, tooltip, jradiobutton

I have a group of JRadioButtons. Each of them points to a directory with only text files, when I mouse over them they should count how many files are in each directory and return the file count as tooltips, I can not set the tooltips when I created the buttons, how to get dynamic tooltips from them ?

I tried the following, but didn't work :

```
JRadioButton myButton=new JRadioButton("Test")
{
  public static final long serialVersionUID=26362862L;
  public String getToolTipText(MouseEvent evt)
  {
    return "123";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Override the `getToolTipText()` method of your radio buttons.

You can then use the `File.listFiles(...)` method to determine the number of files in the directory.

Edit:

It appears that when you override this method you need to manually register the component with the ToolTipManager:

```
ToolTipManager.sharedInstance().registerComponent(radioButton);
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks ! Wonder why registerComponent was decessary here, but it worked !